# How to inherit fields from User in Django admin using custom user?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to add my `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to my admin insted of `User` model.
I register it with the [snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) I found in the docs:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'bdate')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('bdate', 'website', 'location')}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
```

In fieldsets `Personal info` I added all my custom info. Now I also want to display all inherited fields like `first_name`, `username`, etc. I can add them one by one to fieldsets, but I am not sure if that's the right way.

Is there a way just to inherit them from `User` model without specifying explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of `ModelAdmin.get_fieldsets()`:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = list(super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj))
        # update the `fieldsets` with your specific fields
        fieldsets.append(
            ('Personal info', {'fields': ('bdate', 'website', 'location')}))
        return fieldsets
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed. Thanks!