# why can't I log in into any account until I reset its password in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-generic-views

I have a Profile model that has a one to one relationship with the User model from django.contrib.auth.models , when I add a new profile from the admin panel I noticed that the password field is not transformed into dots when typing , it shows the actual password , that's not the issue though , the issue is , when ever I create a new profile which in turns creates a new User , and mark the is staff attribute as true, I can't log in into the admin panel with that created account, unless I reset the password manually with

`python manage.py changepassword the-user-name`

after I have reset the password and only then even with the same password, I can log in into the account normally, does anybody know why is that happening ?
I made sure it's not a mistake in typing the password and I tried it several times until I made sure that this is what is actually happening

**Update**

when I enter the Users model from the Authentication and Authorization section opposed to entering it from the app name, I find that written besides the password section

`Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm`

how can I fix it ?

I forgot to say that I am using an UpdateView from generic views , and using the model Profile as the the model attribute set on that view

the code of my update view

```
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields= [
        'username',
        'bio',
        'avatar_thumbnail',
        'location',
        'tags',
        'contact_information'
        ]
    def get_object(self):
        return Profile.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs.get('user_pk'))

    def get_queryset(self):
        base_qs = super(ProfileUpdate, self).get_queryset()
        return base_qs.filter(username=self.request.user.username)
```

Comment: Is it possible that when you create the account it's not hashing/storing your password properly, so when you reset the password manually it's actually hashed/stored properly thus allowing you to log in?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica how to know if that what's happening ?

Comment: Can you see what the password looks like after creating the account versus how it looks after you change the password?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica when I enter the Users model from the  Authentication and Authorization section opposed to entering it from the app name, I find that written besides the password section 
`Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm`

Comment: Well there you go, that's the problem. Now you can update your question with that infromation and someone may be able to help better.

Comment: So the problem occurs when you create user profile from your custom view and not from the admin section ?? If that is the case you should show us the code for how you save the passwords from your profile view page

Comment: @bhaskarc actually no , I am not creating the user profile from a custome view, I don't have a CreateView yet , I only have an update view that doesn't handle passwords, so the problem occurs when I create the profile user from the admin panel

Comment: you talk about some app name,  can you share the admin code that you use to register the app  ?

Comment: @bhaskarc `admin.site.register(models.Profile)` do you mean this ?

Comment: try the code below. And sorry there was an error in earlier code, instead of model=Profile, simply add a pass as it stands corrected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would inherit from ModelAdmin instead of UserAdmin in your admin.py.

Can you instead try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from app.models import Profile

class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(UserAdmin,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      UserAdmin.fieldsets += (('profile', {'fields': ('attr1', 'attr2')}),)

admin.site.unregister(User)    
admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

**Explanation**

When you registered the `Profile` admin like so, `admin.site.register(models.Profile)`, internally it was inheriting from `ModelAdmin` class which is perfect for all other classes. But for User we need hashing for saving the passwrd field, so there is a separate class UserAdmin that must be inherited from.

Once you inherited, the password issue was resolved but since the base model was UserAdmin, only user related fields were showing. We needed to append the profile fields for which we added the `__init__` method and appended the profile fields to the admin section.

Comment: now it doesn't ask me about any of the attributes I have set on the Profile model and only asks me about the username and password when registering it

Comment: it gives me the line `UserAdmin.fields = list(UserAdmin.fields) + ... `
and gives me the error 
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: it's telling me 
` The value of 'fieldsets[4]', 'fieldsets[5], 'fieldsets[6]'... must be a list or tuple`

Comment: actually this one worked  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34696665/2348704) , but when registering a new user it tells me `Please correct the errors below.` and there are no errors below !!!

Comment: actually the modified comment worked , thank you so much :')

Comment: can you explain to me what's happened or what happened ?